Using outbound template for reserved keyword 'yes' and Y
Is it possible to send an SMS message to contacts which comprises of the Keyword Yes using the outbound template in MobileConnect.
I am aware that I can use the Mobile Opt-In template to do the above as yes is a reserved keyword and can only be used via the Mobile Opt-In template.
